# Tensorflow: combining two tensors with dimension X into one tensor with dimension X+1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am doing some sentiment analysis with Tensorflow, but there is a problem I can't solve:

I have one tensor (input) shaped as `[?, 38] [batch_size, max_word_length]` and one (prediction) shaped as `[?, 3] [batch_size, predicted_label]`.
My goal is to combine both tensors into a single tensor with the shape of [?, 38, 3].
This tensor is used as the input of my second stage.

Seems easy, but i can't find a way of doing it.

Can (and will) you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible. You have tensor, which contains `batch_size * max_word_length` 
 elements and tensor which contains `batch_size * predicted_label` elements. Hence there are

`batch_size * (max_word_length + predicted_label)`

elements. And now you want to create new tensor `[batch_size, max_word_length, predicted_label]` with

`batch_size * max_word_length * predicted_label`

elements. You don't have enough elements for this.

Comment: Well, yeah you are right, so `tf.concat([input, prediction], 1)` leading to `[?, 41]` is the way to go. But how do I perform this on a different feature encoder which gives me a tensor like `[None, 38, 78, 109]` e.g. `[batch_size, words_per_line, chars_per_word, possible_chars_one_hot]`

Comment: And you joined this tensor with what?

Comment: I want to join  the `[None, 38, 78, 109]` e.g. `[batch_size, words_per_line, chars_per_word, possible_chars_one_hot]` tensor with the `[?, 3] [batch_size, predicted_label]` tensor. So I have all the information for the next stage in one place. If this is not possible I need to have a neuronal net with 2 inputs, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318457/how-to-build-a-multiple-input-graph-with-tensor-flow).  B.t.w. thank you for your help.

Comment: Hm. I don't have experience with NN for chars-words and etc. I use NN for CV. But in CV I feed to NN two tensors: one - batch of images `[batch_size, height, width, channels]` and second - batch of labels corresponding to images `[batch_size, labels_for_one_image_cnt]`. I don't concatenate this two tensor, but this is not a problem.
But I am not sure this is same with your case.