# Tensorflow GAN discriminator loss NaN since negativ discriminator output

Tags: python, tensorflow

In [my implementation](https://bitbucket.org/mflender/master_thesis) of a GAN network the output of the discriminator is something like `2.05145e+07` which leads to `1 - disc_output` -> `1-2.05145e+07=-2.05145e+07` (a negativ number) therefore `log(1-2.05145e+07)` leads to NaN.

I am not the first one with this kind of problem. One solution is to only allow positive values inside the `log` like done [here](https://github.com/AYLIEN/gan-intro/blob/master/gan.py#L106).

Does anyone knows any better solution to this?
maybe some different loss function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because discriminator returns a probability value, its output must be between 0 and 1. Try using `sigmoid` ( https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sigmoid) before using discriminator outputs.

Additionally, as others did, I suggest using `tf.log(tf.maximum(x, 1e-9))` in case of a numerical instability.

Comment: I've tried the `sigmoid` activation function, but the result of the discriminator is then `1` which leads to `log(1-1)` which is equally bad. At the moment I use the `tf.log(tf.maximum(x, 1e-9))` but I wonder if there is any better way.

Comment: I think this indicates a problem in your model. Discriminator output represents the probability that the given sample is real. In your case, it assigns probability value `1` to synthetic samples, which doesn't make sense. `tf.log(tf.maximum(x, 1e-9))` is just a precaution against numerical instabilities, not a solution to this problem.

Comment: You made me have a closer look at my model and I thing I found (one of) the error(s). So you relay helped me with my thesis. Have a thousand thanks for this hint. My discriminator has two inputs, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318457/how-to-build-a-multiple-input-graph-with-tensor-flow) and adding both input subnets causes the problem, if I multiply them it seems to work fine.

Comment: Glad this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There are standard techniques to avoid log numerical instability. For example, what you often care about is the loss (which is a function of the log), not the log value itself. For instance, with logistic loss:

For brevity, let `x = logits`, `z = labels`.  The logistic loss is

> z * -log(sigmoid(x)) + (1 - z) * -log(1 - sigmoid(x))
>
> = max(x, 0) - x * z + log(1 + exp(-abs(x)))

These tricks are already implemented in standard tensorflow losses (like `tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy`). Note that the naive solution of taking a max or a min inside of the log **is not** a good solution, since there aren't meaningful gradients in the saturated regions: for instance, `d/dx[max(x, 0)] = 0 for x < 0`, which means there won't be gradients in the saturated region.

TensorFlow has GAN support with `tf.contrib.gan`. These losses already implement all of the standard numerical stability tricks, and an avoid you having to recreate the wheel.

```
tfgan = tf.contrib.gan

tfgan.losses.minimax_discriminator_loss(...)
```

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/gan for more details.